# adding id of person in the function responsable for creating a Company (JEE - webservice)

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am trying to link my **Company** with a specific **Person**, so I decided then to add a parameter in my function (function responsable for creating a Company). Here is the code:

```
@POST
    public Response create(Long idPerson, CompanyDTO company , @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {  
    if(company == null)
        throw ...
    if(idPerson == null)
        throw ...
    CompanyDTO companyUsed = company;
  PersonDTO person =
  this.servicePerson.searchPersonById(idPerson);
  companyUsed.setPerson(person);
  Long idCompany =
  this.service.saveCompany(companyUsed); //serviceCompany
  if(idCompany == null)
  throw ...
  UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
  builder.path(Long.toString(idCompany));
  return Response.created(builder.build()).build();
 }
```

When I don't use **idPerson** in parameters it works well but I specify a static **idPerson** in my code.

```
public Response create(CompanyDTO company , @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
...
PersonDTO person =
this.servicePerson.searchPersonById(1L); // I specify it here statically
... }
```

So here is the problematic I would like to add **idPerson** in my parameters. If I do that I got a 500 error. Here is a part of my exception:

```
 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException 
The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be   
mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize 
instance of java.lang.Long out of START_OBJECT token
```

Answer (score 0):

The person identifier could be defined as a path parameter (it will become part of the URL):

```
@POST
@Path("{idPerson}")
public Response create(@PathParam("idPerson") Long idPerson, 
                       @Context UriInfo uriInfo, CompanyDTO company,) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I do that I got a 405 error (method not allowed) @Molin

Comment: @ysd What is your request like?

Comment: If I understand well what you did in your code it should be this URL POST **/companies/idPerson (so I create a Person) and then I did POST **link/companies/1** and it doesn't work and of course POST **link/companies** does not work. I would like to associate a company with one person for exemple and the problem is how to specify this person. My header ** Content-Type application/json** Body Company JSON.@Molin

Comment: @Molin you forgot \{} in your solution, anyway but it's not what I want to do what you propose link Company1 with person1 and company2 with company2 not company1 with person in my choice. Otherwise, I would like to have this URL **link/companies** and then create **link/companies/1** and then see in my JSON the person I choose.

Comment: @ysd Thanks, I've missed the curly braces in the `@Path` annotation value. I'm still unsure about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Molin I would like to do a thing like this. In my visual part (Symfony), I would like when I type **/companies** to get information about all companies and then when I add a company to be added in **/companies** not in **/companies/idPerson** , What I would like exactly to do: in symfony, in my url/companies/create I fill my data and I click into a buttom called addPerson and then choose then person and then send it to JEE.

Comment: @Molin To summarize, I would like to be able to link the first company I create with Person1 or Person2 or Person3 not specifacly Person1, in what you propose we are obliged to link comany1 with Person1 and so on. In addition to that the fact linked to URLs. Thanks anyway